# Correct YAML format for kubernetes migration

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I have a YAML file as like below which I have exported from an existing cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2019-03-20T23:17:42Z
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "80999"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/default
    uid: 5c6e0d09-4b66-11e9-b4e3-0a779a87bb40
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    creationTimestamp: 2020-04-21T05:46:25Z
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "113455688"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/pod-labeler
    uid: 702dadda-8393-11ea-abd9-0a768ca51346
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

If I do the above YAML and apply to a new cluster, I get an error, which is out of the scope of this question.

In summary, I have to get rid of the below attributes:

```
uid:
selfLink:
resourceVersion:
creationTimestamp:
```

So I got a sed command like below which does the trick

```
sed -i '/uid: \|selfLink: \|resourceVersion: \|creationTimestamp: /d' dev4-serviceaccounts.yaml
```

The final YAML file is like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
metadata:
```

My question is, is it the correct YAML file as it erases the empty tag and values for metadata...(AT the very much last of the YAML file)

I can create objects - serviceaccounts in this instance, but I just want to ensure if I am doing is correct or any other better approach.

Comment: You should remove the last `metadata:` line. You don't need to re-create the `default` serviceaccount. Creating ServiceAccounts, you shouldn't set their `secrets` / would be done by whichever controller handles creation for your serviceaccount. Otherwise: you should re-create the corresponding Secrets objects. The annotations you have are not mandatory / would be re-added if you kubectl apply your file.

Comment: Where did these objects come from originally?  Can you check the original source out and run `helm install` or `kubectl apply -f` on files from that source tree, without trying to export the existing objects?

Comment: Yes, secret will also migrate from Original Cluster and namespace to Target cluster and namespace. What I show up here is the YAML file format.

Comment: These originated from the export of the target cluster and a specific namespace

Comment: @SYN I am applying kubectl apply if secret.yaml for all namespaces as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze and SYN I hope you both got all information from my side?

Comment: be careful reapplying all secrets. unless you did create them in the first place, you shouldn't need to migrate them. there could be secrets with certificates for your kubernetes dashboard, certificates for your nodes, generated by operators, ... depending on your cluster, this could end poorly.

Comment: Sure @SYN  will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case this is correct but you need to be carefull with it since there is no consistent way to do this for all types of resources.

Historically kubectl had --export flag that was generating yamls ready to apply, but it got depricated because of many bugs. Check out [the issue on k8s github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/73787) for more details.

There is also another way to export the resources if you used `kubectl apply` to create it.

```
kubectl apply view-last-applied <api-resource> <name> -oyaml
e.g.:
kubectl apply view-last-applied serviceaccount pod-labeler -oyaml
```

But remember that this won't work for resources created with helm or other tools.

The best thing you could do is to always keep all your source files in git or similar, so you don't ever need to export it.

Comment: Super, Thanks a lot Matt, this is certainly helpful!